# Captivate setVariableValue won't show full string?

Tags: javascript, setvalue, adobe-captivate

I'm setting up a quiz in captivate. At the end of the quiz it displays notes about the incorrect answers in a text box on a slide, but when I test it, only part of the string will show and will cut off in the middle of the string. It is not due to the text box being too small.

I have it set up like:

```
textArray[0] = "Here is some note about an incorrectly answered question.";

window.cpAPIInterface.setVariableValue("textBox", textArray[0]);

// where textBox is a captivate variable.
```

When tested, it will show something like

"Here is some note ab"

Answer (score 0):

It's probably to late but maybe this will help someone else.
The variable's max length is set to something too short to hold all of the text you are trying to put into it:

1. double click the text box so as to edit the text content
2. With the property inspecter, click on the Insert Variable icon[image]
3. Select the user variable you want to add
4. Change the max length to something that will hold all the text
   [image]